# Why is my IE-conditional comment causing a compilation error when not added via Response.Write?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a page that has the conditional comment:

```
<%@ Page language="c#"  %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ASP.NET Application</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/json_parse.js"></script><![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    test
  </body>
<html>
```

When I do it like above, it throws a compilation error saying it expects a closing "script" tag. But the below code (which should end up with the same page) works perfectly:

```
<%@ Page language="c#"  %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ASP.NET Application</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <% Response.Write( "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"scripts/json_parse.js\"></script>" ); %>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    test
  </body>
<html>
```

Why does it have a problem with IE conditionals? The script tag is inside a comment and is not "runat".

Comment: FYI - These IE conditionals aren't supported by IE10 when running in standards mode.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a case where you want the conditional comments to be revealed to downlevel browsers, not hidden by uplevel browsers, so there is a slightly different syntax to use:

```
<![if lt IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/json_parse.js"></script>
<![endif]>
```

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for detailed information.

Comment: will that cause problems in any other browsers? Since it's not hidden in a coment?